# how to put an SVG element (created with Rapheal JS lib) into a DIV element (to make RMB click managment)

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

My prime goal is to have a Right Mouse Button click detection for each SVG element (created with Raphael JS lib), my html code for this looks very straightforward:

```
<head>
 ...
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/side_media/js/raphael.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/side_media/js/MyScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
 <div id="canvas_container">
</body>
```

and my JS contains

```
window.onload = function() {
 var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 900, 400);
 ...
surface[1] = paper.path('m150,150l40,0l0,20l-40,0l0,-20z');
surface[2] = paper.path('m150,150l-10,-20c20,-17 40,-17 60,0l-10,20l-40,0z');
surface[3] = paper.path('m190,170l10,20c16,-20 16,-40 0,-60l-10,20l0,20z');
surface[4] = paper.path('m190,170l10,20c-20,17 -40,17 -60,0l10,-20l40,0z');
surface[5] = paper.path('m150,150l-10,-20c-16,20 -16,40 0,60l10,-20l0,-20z');
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)    
  fill[i]=surface[i].attr({fill:'#FFFFFF'});

//each element has its own url activated on click (LMB)
toothfill[1].click(function (){window.location="http:...";});
...
}
```

I have also tried many (available on web as examples) JS scripts which show some menu on RMB click and it looks that it would be possible to restrict this RMB menu only to some selected html DIV class (please warn me if not!), so my problem right now is: howto put those "fill" array elements into seperate DIV which would share the same class?

If there is any other easier way to do it - I am open :)
thanks a lot in advance,
Borys

I would like to know is it possible to put each SVG element into a separate DIV, just ? I would like

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you'd need to wrap the svg in a div just to check which mouse button was pressed.

Try something like this instead:

```
toothfill[1].click(function (evt){ 
  if (evt.button == 0) {
    // left mouse button pressed
  } 
  else (evt.button == 1) {
    // right mouse button pressed
    evt.preventDefault(); // prevent right-click menu from appearing
  }
});
```

Here's the [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click) for the click Event object from DOM 3 Events. And read up on [Event.preventDefault](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-preventDefault) if you don't know what it is.